# How do I extract the X value with the maximum Y values?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I would like to display the X value in my histogram at which the maximum Y values are present. I followed the example on the page: [Find the x value corresponding to a histogram max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818905/find-the-x-value-corresponding-to-a-histogram-max)

and wrote this:

```
def Plot_show_us(dfus, dfdus, dfnus):
    x = dfus['O18ad']
    bins=[-22,(...),22] # normaly here are a lot of Bins 
    n, b, patches =plt.hist(x, bins, alpha=0.65, label='old')
    bin_max = np.where(n == n.max())
    print('maxbin'), b[bin_max][0]
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
```

However, I couldn't get any output! What am I doing wrong (I think this is a beginner's mistake)?

my output:

```
Plot_show_us(dfus, dfdus, dfnus)
maxbin
```

Comment: You must return a variable if you want the function get that as an output. `return maxbin`

Comment: Or, just to display, change the `print` statement to: `print('maxbin', b[bin_max][0])`. Notice the `)` moves to the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
print('maxbin: %i'%b[bin_max][0])
```

or

```
print('maxbin: '+str(b[bin_max][0]))
```

Comment: Not needed. OP's code has a typo, just `print('maxbin', b[bin_max][0])` will work fine.